# User ID not posting to Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to allow logged-in users post a title and description with their Google ID to Firebase, but the user ID is giving an undefined error in the console.

The error is only triggered when addIdea() function is called, when the form is posted. Form elements are simply ng-models for title and desc.

```
var app = angular.module("fluttrApp", ["firebase"]);

app.controller("fluttrCtrl", function($scope, $firebase) {

var ref = new Firebase("[forge].firebaseio.com/ideas");

      var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function(error, user) {
        if (!user) {
            auth.login('google', {
              rememberMe: true
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log(user.displayName);
            console.log(user.uid)

            $scope.displayName = user.displayName;
            $scope.uid = user.uid;

        }

        });

var sync = $firebase(ref);


$scope.ideas = sync.$asArray();


$scope.title = "";
$scope.desc = "";

$scope.addIdea = function(title, desc, uid) {

$scope.displayName = user.displayName;
$scope.uid = user.uid;

$scope.ideas.$add(
    {
        "title": title, 
        "desc": desc,
        "user": uid
    }
    );
//The user id needs to be pulled and we need to post
//the idea id generated here to the user branch
$scope.title = '';
$scope.desc = '';
}

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `user` is *undefined* because it is out of the scope of the `$scope.addIdea() function`.

It exists only in the callback of `FirebaseSimpleLogin` call.

Take a look at this example [Monitoring Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication) for reference.